# Algorithm for counting number of zeros from sorted array containing 0s and 1s.

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to improve the running time of  my algorithm that counts the total number of 0s in an input array. The input array has a length n and consisting of 0s and 1s which are arranged in sorted order.

My algorithm so far is :

```
Algorithm : zeroCount(A)
Input : An sorted array A containing 0s and 1s
Output : total number of 0s in A

if A[0]=1 then 
    return 0;
len <— A.length
if A[len-1]=0 then
    return len
count <— 0
i <—0
for  i<len do           
    if A[i]==0 then 
        count++
    i++
return count
```

Java  implementation is:

```
public int zeroCount(int[] a){

    if(a[0]==1)
    return 0;
    int length =a.length;
    if(a[length-1]==0)
        return length;
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<length&&a[i]==0;i++){
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

However, the running time is O(n).  Any suggestions for improving the running time of this algorithm would be appreciated .

Comment: Applying binary search.

Comment: It's sorted. Do a binary search for where the 0/1 transition is.

Comment: This is probably just an exercise, but why store 0 and 1 in a sorted array in the first place? I can't imagine a usecase for doing that.

Comment: @DVT Can you please tell me how to use BST

Comment: @BijayRegmi google for "binary search", read, and try something.

Comment: @Bijay i mean binary search not BST . Please see my answer .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the input array is already sorted , you can use binary search for better performance. This improves the running time to O(log n).

The algorithm which uses binary search is :

```
Algorithm : zeroCount(A)
Input : sorted array A containing 0s and 1s
Output : total number of 0s in A

if A[0]=1 then 
    return 0;
len <— A.length
if A[len-1]=0 then
    return len
 return  count(A,0,length)


Algorithm : count(A,lower,upper)
Input :  sorted array A , integers lower and upper 
Output : total number of 0s in A

mid <— (lower+upper) / 2

if A[mid] != A[mid-1] then 
    return mid

if A[mid] != A[mid+1] then
    return mid+1

if A[mid] = 1 then 
    return count(A,lower,mid-1)

if A[mid] = 0 then 
       return count(A,mid+1,upper)
```

Java implementation :

```
public int zeroCount(int[] a) {

    if (a[0] == 1)    // all are 1
        return 0;
    int length = a.length;
    if (a[length - 1] == 0)   //all are 0
        return length;

    return count(a, 0, length);
}

public int count(int[] a, int lower, int upper) {
    int mid = (lower + upper) / 2;
    if (a[mid] != a[mid - 1])   
        return mid;

    if (a[mid] != a[mid + 1])    
        return mid + 1;

    if (a[mid] == 1) {                // all are 1 above mid 
        return count(a, lower, mid - 1);  
    } else if (a[mid] == 0) {              // all are 0 below mid 
        return count(a, mid + 1, upper);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor quibble: this is a binary search, not a binary search **tree**.  A binary search tree is a tree-like data structure where the child nodes are ordered in a certain way with respect to the parent nodes based on data in the nodes.

Comment: Oho yes its just a typo i have updated my answer .Thank you @DavidChoweller

Comment: @Surace Can you please tell me the logic about base case?

Comment: This algorithm is flawed in that it could overflow with large index values. Also, regarding "This improves the running time from O(n) to o(n)", did you mean "... to O(log n)"?

Comment: The count algorithm actually finds the transition between 0 and 1 in the input array and the as @KathyA suggested in the comment above.

Comment: Base case checks the transition between 0/1 and return the number of 0s.

Comment: @LewBloch i have updated my answer. Well,if you mean for large number of input elements , i dont think it would overflow.

Comment: It's unlikely, but an array or list with enough members could find `lower+upper` yielding a negative value.

Answer (score 3):

You can tweak binary search to find the last occurrence (say, index i) of 0 in your array. The count of 0s then will (i+1).

```
  int CountOfZeroes(int[] A, int key)
        {
            int low = 0;
            int high = A.size - 1;              
            int result = -1;

            while (low <= high)
            {
                int mid = low + (high-low)/2;

                if (A[mid] == key)
                {
                    result = mid;
                    low = mid + 1;
                }
                else if (key < A[mid])
                {
                    high = mid - 1;
                }
                else 
                {
                    low = mid + 1;
                }
            }

            return result + 1;              
        }
```

You will call the above function with key set to 0. The time complexity will be `O(log n)`.